# How to display another widget if the collection is empty?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection A in cloud Firestore which is empty for now but later it will be filled, I want to display a widget like Text("No Data") when there is no data in it.
This is my code

```
class Green extends StatefulWidget {
  const Green({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Green> createState() => _GreenState();
}

class _GreenState extends State<Green> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(uid)
          .where("gatename", isEqualTo: "A")
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (_, snapshot2) {
        if (snapshot2.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot2.error}');

        if (snapshot2.hasData) {
          final ds = snapshot2.data!.docs;
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 600,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: ds.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                  final d = ds[i].data();
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(d["time"].toString()),
                    leading: Text(d["gatename"].toString()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

I have used `else if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty){}`
but it is still showing white screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
`if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.isEmpty)` - this case can be worked.
```

Comment: Thanks, but .isEmpty throws error saying no such method or instance is created perhaps..i solved it by " (snapshot2.data?.size == 0)"

Answer (score 0):

You can check the data you've received

```
if (snapshot2.hasData) {
  if (snapshot2.data==null || snapshot2.data.isEmpty) {
    return Text('No Data');
  } else {
    final ds = snapshot2.data!.docs;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 600,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: ds.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, i) {
            final d = ds[i].data();
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(d["time"].toString()),
              leading: Text(d["gatename"].toString()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but .isEmpty throws error saying no such method or instance is created perhaps..i solved it by " (snapshot2.data?.size == 0)"

Comment: In that case use if (snapshot2.data==null || snapshot2.data.isEmpty). This should do it! I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are just checking if the data exists and not if it's empty.

You should also check if the data is empty:

```
if (snapshot2.hasData && snapshot2.data == null) {
   return widget1
} else {
   return widget2
}
```

A cleaner way of doing if-else in dart:

```
snapshot2.hasData && snapshot2.data == null
   ? widget1
   : widget2
```

Comment: Thanks, but .isEmpty throws error saying no such method or instance is created perhaps..i solved it by " (snapshot2.data?.size == 0)"

Comment: Alright, I will update my answer.